# Tornado: complex template rendering using only template.Loader

Tags: python, tornado

I have the following code to test template rendering:

```
import os

from tornado.template import Loader

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loader = Loader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"))

    def simple_template(self):
        tmpl = self.loader.load("utf8.html")
        result = tmpl.generate()
        print result

    def complex_template(self, message):
        tmpl = self.loader.load("message.html")
        result = tmpl.generate(message = message)
        print result

a = A()
a.simple_template()
a.complex_template({"id" : 'asdsadfasd', "from": 'sdfsafd', "body": 'sdfdasfd'})
```

And these are my templates:

templates/utf8.html

```
Héllo
```

templates/message.html

```
<div class="message" id="m{{ message["id"] }}"><b>{{ message["from"] }}: </b>{% module linkify(message["body"]) %}</div>
```

This is the output:

```
Héllo

ERROR:root:message.html code:
 1  def _execute():  # message.html:0
 2      _buffer = []  # message.html:0
 3      _append = _buffer.append  # message.html:0
 4      _append('<div class="message" id="m')  # message.html:1
 5      _tmp = message["id"]  # message.html:1
 6      if isinstance(_tmp, _string_types): _tmp = _utf8(_tmp)  # message.html:1
 7      else: _tmp = _utf8(str(_tmp))  # message.html:1
 8      _tmp = _utf8(xhtml_escape(_tmp))  # message.html:1
 9      _append(_tmp)  # message.html:1
10      _append('"><b>')  # message.html:1
11      _tmp = message["from"]  # message.html:1
12      if isinstance(_tmp, _string_types): _tmp = _utf8(_tmp)  # message.html:1
13      else: _tmp = _utf8(str(_tmp))  # message.html:1
14      _tmp = _utf8(xhtml_escape(_tmp))  # message.html:1
15      _append(_tmp)  # message.html:1
16      _append(': </b>')  # message.html:1
17      _tmp = _modules.linkify(message["body"])  # message.html:1
18      if isinstance(_tmp, _string_types): _tmp = _utf8(_tmp)  # message.html:1
19      else: _tmp = _utf8(str(_tmp))  # message.html:1
20      _append(_tmp)  # message.html:1
21      _append('</div>\n')  # message.html:2
22      return _utf8('').join(_buffer)  # message.html:0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "template_test2.py", line 21, in <module>
    a.complex_template({"id" : 'asdsadfasd', "from": 'sdfsafd', "body": 'sdfdasfd'})
  File "template_test2.py", line 16, in complex_template
    result = tmpl.generate(message = message)
  File "/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-wavilon1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/template.py", line 254, in generate
    return execute()
  File "message_html.generated.py", line 17, in _execute
NameError: global name '_modules' is not defined
```

As you can see, the simple template is rendering as expected, but the complex one is failing. How can I render complex templates *without* defining an application? I just want to use the template rendering facility of tornado in this case.

Comment: Are you sure your template has the right syntax? I think you should not use `linkify` with `module`-

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:
`self.render_string("message.html", message=message)`